# Netbeans 8 with Pentium D and 1.5 gb ram

Tags: netbeans, hardware

At the moment, I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Pentium D 3.0ghz with 1.5GB of RAM. 
Netbeans 8 is really slow. My question is: Would 4GB of DDR2 RAM speed Netbeans up?

Comment: I am running ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely yes. Though you should be able to see in some system monitor if it the problem in your setup is CPU or memory or I/O or some mix of these. There were some performance tweaks in https://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/index.html or http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Performance - while some of them are out of date you can get the idea